# Matplotlib, how to fix gender separation in import file

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm creating a grouped bar chart, in order to print the total of each of the three olympic medals (gold, silver and bronze) separated by sex, the problem is that on the x axis it's printing the sex of each individual athlete (several times, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NbVr.png)) , instead, print "M" and "F" once time for all individuals

Code(incomplete, I'm working on limiting medals by country and Olympic season winter/summer):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv


def GenerateBarChart(a, b):
    plt.bar(x1, Gold, s, color='plum', label='Gold')
    plt.bar(x2, Silver, s, color='peru', label='Silver')
    plt.bar(x3, Bronze, s, color='darkblue', label='Bronze')
    ax.set_ylabel('Values')
    ax.set_title('Grouped')
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_xticks(a)
    ax.set_xticklabels(b)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=5.5)
    plt.show()
    plt.close


def PrintBarChart():
    GenerateBarChart(x1, Sex)


Sex = []
NOC = []
Season = []
Medal = []

with open('compactado.csv', 'r', newline="") as arq:
    reader = csv.reader(arq)
    next(reader)
    for column in csv.reader(arq):
        if len(column) == 0:
            break
        else:
            Sex.append(column[2])
            column[10] = column[10].replace(',', '')
            Season.append(column[10])
            column[7] = column[7].replace(',', '')
            NOC.append(column[7])
            column[14] = column[14].replace(',', '')
            Medal.append(column[14])

s = 0.3

x1 = range(len(Sex))
x2 = [x - s for x in x1]
x3 = [x + s for x in x1]

Season = list(map(str, Season))
NOC = list(map(str, NOC))
Medal = list(map(str, Medal))

Gold = 0
if Medal=="Gold":
   Gold += 1

Silver = 0
if Medal=="Silver":
   Silver += 1

Bronze = 0
if Medal=="Bronze":
   Bronze += 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Part of the File:

```
ID,"Name","Sex","Age","Height","Weight","Team","NOC","Games","Year","Season","City","Sport","Event","Medal"
1,"Arvo Ossian Aaltonen","M",22,NA,NA,"Finland","FIN","1912 Summer",1912,"Summer","Stockholm","Swimming","Swimming Men's 200 metres Breaststroke",NA
1,"Arvo Ossian Aaltonen","M",22,NA,NA,"Finland","FIN","1912 Summer",1912,"Summer","Stockholm","Swimming","Swimming Men's 400 metres Breaststroke",NA
1,"Arvo Ossian Aaltonen","M",30,NA,NA,"Finland","FIN","1920 Summer",1920,"Summer","Antwerpen","Swimming","Swimming Men's 200 metres Breaststroke","Bronze"
1,"Arvo Ossian Aaltonen","M",30,NA,NA,"Finland","FIN","1920 Summer",1920,"Summer","Antwerpen","Swimming","Swimming Men's 400 metres Breaststroke","Bronze"
2,"Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen","M",28,184,85,"Finland","FIN","2014 Winter",2014,"Winter","Sochi","Ice Hockey","Ice Hockey Men's Ice Hockey","Bronze"
3,"Paavo Johannes Aaltonen","M",28,175,64,"Finland","FIN","1948 Summer",1948,"Summer","London","Gymnastics","Gymnastics Men's Team All-Around","Gold"
4,"Kjetil Andr Aamodt","M",22,176,85,"Norway","NOR","1994 Winter",1994,"Winter","Lillehammer","Alpine Skiing","Alpine Skiing Men's Downhill","Silver"
5,"Leila Abdelmoez","F",19,160,46,"Egypt","EGY","2016 Summer",2016,"Summer","Rio de Janeiro","Synchronized Swimming","Synchronized Swimming Women's Team",NA
6,"Reema Abdo","F",21,173,59,"Canada","CAN","1984 Summer",1984,"Summer","Los Angeles","Swimming","Swimming Women's 4 x 100 metres Medley Relay","Bronze"
7,"Mona Ahmad Abdulaziz Hassanein","F",26,166,61,"Egypt","EGY","2012 Summer",2012,"Summer","London","Fencing","Fencing Women's epee, Individual",NA
8,"Zagalav Abdulbekovich Abdulbekov","M",26,160,62,"Soviet Union","URS","1972 Summer",1972,"Summer","Munich","Wrestling","Wrestling Men's Featherweight, Freestyle","Gold"
9,"Irene Abel","F",19,160,48,"East Germany","GDR","1972 Summer",1972,"Summer","Munich","Gymnastics","Gymnastics Women's Team All-Around","Silver"
10,"Nicola Virginia Adams","F",33,164,51,"Great Britain","GBR","2016 Summer",2016,"Summer","Rio de Janeiro","Boxing","Boxing Women's Flyweight","Gold"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid reinventing the wheel, I suggest that you import the dataset with the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html) package into a DataFrame object by using the [read_csv function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html#min-tut-02-read-write) and that you create the grouped bar chart with the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) package which has been built on top of matplotlib to provide an easy way to create this type of plot (among many others). Here is how you can plot the sample of data by using the [countplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

```py
import pandas as pd    # v 1.2.5
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.1

df = pd.read_csv('compactado.csv')
df.head()
```

[image: df]

```py
sns.countplot(data=df, x='Medal', hue='Sex')
```

[image: countplot]